# Wordpress Featured Post

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to find a good plugin that would take the 4 most recent news articles, or filtered for a category, and allow me to make a auto rotating slider. Which includes a large image, a title, and a excerpt (not content) from a post. And also taking the image, or featured image as the navigation of the slides.

Does anyone know of such plugin? I am having little luck finding one that does most of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [SlideDeck](http://www.slidedeck.com/) in the past. They offer a [free version](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slidedeck-lite-for-wordpress/) so you can play around with it, and with a little programming you can display anything you want in it. I ended up not using it because it was overkill for what I needed and just coded my own slider with jQuery.

Comment: That looks really good. If I knew a little more I am sure I could do my own with jQuery sliders, just not sure how to call what I want in a custom template.

Comment: feel free to accept it as your answer be selecting the checkbox or upvoting it :)